# CSS: Create a custom grid with Image, Text and Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface

Is there a way to create a grid just like this

[image]

1. It should have a Transistion effect in hover of the whole grid.
2. click on the whole image(anywhere in the grid) should open a link
3. The "Sample Data" link should be a separate link for a separate page or popup.

Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: What do you mean by a "transition effect" on hover?

Comment: Like on hover of the grid, the grid comes a 5% bigger then other grids to indicate that it is beings hoveredon

Comment: _"Is there a way to create a grid just like this"_? Yes. What have you attempted so far?